# Getting android the method findViewbyId(int) is undefined for the type QuoteFormActivity?

Tags: android

I don't see why i get the error, `findViewById()` is owned by the Activity class, right? So extending it would be all it takes.

For quoteText and btnSendQuote i get the error messages, how can fix this and what is the cause?

```
    public class QuoteFormActivity extends Activity {

        //VARIABLES from FORM
        EditText quoteText;
        Button btnSendQuote;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote_form);

            quoteText = (EditText) findByViewId(R.id.et_quote);
            btnSendQuote = (Button) findByViewId(R.id.btn_send_quote);

            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            //setupActionBar();
        }
```

ps: already made a clean buitl

Comment: shows us your import statments.

Comment: Imports are too long for a comment but here's `import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;`

Comment: `import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;`

Comment: change `findByViewId` to `findViewById`

Answer (score 3):

Its `findViewById` not `findByViewId`

Comment: OH MAN, it's getting too late tx. Didn't see the typo, my bad. *feeling ashamed

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
quoteText = (EditText) findByViewId(R.id.et_quote);
btnSendQuote = (Button) findByViewId(R.id.btn_send_quote);
```

to:

```
quoteText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_quote);
btnSendQuote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send_quote);
```